# Using a Switch statement to output to a form from Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

I am trying capture the number of vowels in input text, add them to an array, and then output the results to a form. The first part of my Javascript works fine (i.e. it uses the regular expressions to count the data as required). However, when I add them to the array and try to output a sorted list to colour code the top 3 results, my script fails.

Can anyone help me where I've gone wrong?

```js
function countVowels() {
  var str = document.getElementById('inputTextUser').value;
  var countA = 0;
  var countE = 0;
  var countI = 0;
  var countO = 0;
  var countU = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i).match(/[a-z]/i) !== null) {
      if (str.charAt(i).match(/a/i)) {
        countA++;
      }
      if (str.charAt(i).match(/e/i)) {
        countE++;
      }
      if (str.charAt(i).match(/i/i)) {
        countI++;
      }
      if (str.charAt(i).match(/o/i)) {
        countO++;
      }
      if (str.charAt(i).match(/u/i)) {
        countU++;
      }
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("vowelsA").value = countA;
  document.getElementById("vowelsE").value = countE;
  document.getElementById("vowelsI").value = countI;
  document.getElementById("vowelsO").value = countO;
  document.getElementById("vowelsU").value = countU;

  var vowelCounts = new Array();
  vowelCounts[0] = countA;
  vowelCounts[1] = countE;
  vowelCounts[2] = countI;
  vowelCounts[3] = countO;
  vowelCounts[4] = countU;

  vowelCounts.sort();

  var length = vowelCounts.length; //gets the array's length once before the loop    
  var bigOne = vowelCounts[-1];

  //Set background color for the first three higher counts.
  var color = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
  for (i = 0; i < length - 2; i++) {
    switch (bigOne) {
      case avowel:
        document.getElementById("vowelsA").style.backgroundColor = color[i];
        avowel = "";
        break;
      case evowel:
        document.getElementById("vowelsE").style.backgroundColor = color[i];
        evowel = "";
        break;
      case ivowel:
        document.getElementById("vowelsI").style.backgroundColor = color[i];
        ivowel = "";
        break;
      case ovowel:
        document.getElementById("vowelsO").style.backgroundColor = color[i];
        ovowel = "";
        break;
      case uvowel:
        document.getElementById("vowelsU").style.backgroundColor = color[i];
        uvowel = "";
        break;
    }
    bigOne = vowelCounts[length - 2 - i];
  }
}
```

Hugely appreciated!

Comment: Fails how?  Are you getting an error or is it just not doing what you want?

Comment: You seem to have left out any declaration of avowel, evowel, ivowel, ovowel and uvowel. I assume you intended to use them to sync with the sorted array in some fashion?

Comment: `var bigOne = vowelCounts[-1];` this looks like to be the cause. Index `-1` was not existed in the array so `bigOne` would be `undefined`

Comment: @drs9222 I was not getting what I had hoped from the output (and no error in the IDE to help where I'd gone wrong); the string matching calculated the number of vowels correctly, and displayed them in the element as expected. However, I couldn't generate the background colours for the element from the array. I now realise from feedback here there's at least one good reason for that!

Comment: @SMcCrohan You hit the nail on the head! I had decided to do that, then changed my mind and edited the script without changing the variables. Couldn't see the wood for the trees. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that stands out is that your switch is looking for variables like `avowel` that don't seem to exist.

If you meant the `countA` and `avowel` variables to be the same then maybe it could work if you tweaked it like this...

```
var vowelCounts = new Array();
  vowelCounts[0] = avowel;
  vowelCounts[1] = evowel;
  vowelCounts[2] = ivowel;
  vowelCounts[3] = ovowel;
  vowelCounts[4] = uvowel;

  vowelCounts.sort();


  //Set background color for the first three higher counts.
  var color = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var bigOne = vowelCounts[i];
    switch (bigOne) {
      case avowel:
        document.getElementById("vowelsA").style.backgroundColor = color[i];
        avowel = "";
        break;
      case evowel:
        document.getElementById("vowelsE").style.backgroundColor = color[i];
        evowel = "";
        break;
      case ivowel:
        document.getElementById("vowelsI").style.backgroundColor = color[i];
        ivowel = "";
        break;
      case ovowel:
        document.getElementById("vowelsO").style.backgroundColor = color[i];
        ovowel = "";
        break;
      case uvowel:
        document.getElementById("vowelsU").style.backgroundColor = color[i];
        uvowel = "";
        break;
    }
  }
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1x0s99ks/).  Of course this won't work if there are ties in the top 3 but it seems to be what you were trying to do.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/9g9mbonn/) is better one that will handle ties and doesn't need a switch.

```
var avowel = 4;
var evowel = 2;
var ivowel = 2;
var ovowel = 1;
var uvowel = 3;


var vowelCounts = new Array();
  vowelCounts[0] = { element: document.getElementById("vowelsA"), count: avowel};
  vowelCounts[1] = { element: document.getElementById("vowelsE"), count: evowel};
  vowelCounts[2] = { element: document.getElementById("vowelsI"), count: ivowel};
  vowelCounts[3] = { element: document.getElementById("vowelsO"), count: ovowel};
  vowelCounts[4] = { element: document.getElementById("vowelsU"), count: uvowel};

  vowelCounts.sort(function(i1,i2){ return i1.count-i2.count});
  // Uncomment if I got the order backwords from what you wanted
  //vowelCounts.reverse();

  var length = vowelCounts.length; //gets the array's length once before the loop    


  //Set background color for the first three higher counts.
  var color = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var bigOne = vowelCounts[i];    
    bigOne.element.style.backgroundColor = color[i];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for putting me right on the initial implementation; I couldn't see the wood for the trees with the variables, d'oh! The second version you propose is much more elegant, and indeed efficient, without the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here's probably a solution you want:

```
function countVowels() {
  var str = document.getElementById('inputTextUser').value;
  var countA = { letter: 'A', count: 0 };
  var countE = { letter: 'E', count: 0 };
  var countI = { letter: 'I', count: 0 };
  var countO = { letter: 'O', count: 0 };
  var countU = { letter: 'U', count: 0 };

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i).match(/[a-z]/i) !== null) {
      if (str.charAt(i).match(/a/i)) {
        countA.count++;
      }
      if (str.charAt(i).match(/e/i)) {
        countE.count++;
      }
      if (str.charAt(i).match(/i/i)) {
        countI.count++;
      }
      if (str.charAt(i).match(/o/i)) {
        countO.count++;
      }
      if (str.charAt(i).match(/u/i)) {
        countU.count++;
      }
    }
  }

  document.getElementById("vowelsA").value = countA;
  document.getElementById("vowelsE").value = countE;
  document.getElementById("vowelsI").value = countI;
  document.getElementById("vowelsO").value = countO;
  document.getElementById("vowelsU").value = countU;

  vowelCounts.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.count<b.count;
  });
  var color = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
//Set background color for the first three higher counts.
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
      var vowel = vowelCount[i].letter;
      document.getElementById("vowels"+vowel).style.backgroundColor = color[i];
  }

  }
}
```